# Add leading zero to number in file name across nested directories

Tags: rename, zsh, file-rename

I'm using `zsh`

I know I can rename file with leading zeros using a command like:

`rename -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' -- *.tif`

I have a directory structure like this

```
root/
root/foo/
root/foo/a
root/foo/b
root/foo/c
root/bar/
root/bar/a
root/bar/b
root/bar/c
```

I'd like to apply the command above in each directory.

I've tried doing something like

`find . -type d -exec "rename -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' -- {}/*.tif" \;`

However, I get `No such file or directory` when the directory is empty (just contains other directories) and none of the `.tif` files in the structure have been renamed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `zmv` plus `EXTENDED_GLOB`:

```sh
% cd $(mktemp -d)
% dirs=(root root/{foo,bar}/{,a,b,c})
% mkdir -p $dirs[@]
% touch $^dirs/1.tif
% print -c **(.)
root/1.tif        root/bar/b/1.tif  root/foo/a/1.tif
root/bar/1.tif    root/bar/c/1.tif  root/foo/b/1.tif
root/bar/a/1.tif  root/foo/1.tif    root/foo/c/1.tif
% autoload -Uz zmv
% setopt extendedglob
% zmv -Mv '(**/)(<->)(.tif)' '$1${(l:2::0:)2}$3'
mv -- root/bar/a/1.tif root/bar/a/01.tif
mv -- root/bar/b/1.tif root/bar/b/01.tif
mv -- root/bar/c/1.tif root/bar/c/01.tif
mv -- root/bar/1.tif root/bar/01.tif
mv -- root/foo/a/1.tif root/foo/a/01.tif
mv -- root/foo/b/1.tif root/foo/b/01.tif
mv -- root/foo/c/1.tif root/foo/c/01.tif
mv -- root/foo/1.tif root/foo/01.tif
mv -- root/1.tif root/01.tif
% print -c **(.)
root/01.tif        root/bar/b/01.tif  root/foo/a/01.tif
root/bar/01.tif    root/bar/c/01.tif  root/foo/b/01.tif
root/bar/a/01.tif  root/foo/01.tif    root/foo/c/01.tif
```

Documentation:

- [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv)
- [`EXTENDED_GLOB`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)